# Android studio avd always not booting? What should i do if I want to run emulator on my laptop?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, ram

My laptop configuration:

OS - Windows 7 Ultimate x64 (Dell N5010)

[image: System configuration]

I have installed android studio 2.1.2 (Latest version on today(22/06/2016)).

And I have installed all packages of tools, extras, API23, API22, API21 Folders in android sdk manager.

And I have created AVD like all possible ways. but always AVD Starting and won't boot to home screen. stuck on android boot screen. Refer below image.

[image]

Default 1536 MB ram for avd. And 2 GB for HAX. Tried both x86 and x86_64 System image.

AVD Console showing like below:

```
C:\Users\Siva\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_4_API_23
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 128MB
Could not load func glBindFramebuffer
Could not load func glGenFramebuffers
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
Could not load func glFramebufferTexture2D
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
Could not load func glCheckFramebufferStatus
Could not load func glDeleteFramebuffers
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
Could not load func glIsRenderbuffer
Could not load func glBindRenderbuffer
Could not load func glDeleteRenderbuffers
Could not load func glGenRenderbuffers
Could not load func glRenderbufferStorage
Could not load func glGetRenderbufferParameteriv
Could not load func glFramebufferRenderbuffer
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
```

Ram and processor running fully. this is my CPU meter gadget.

[image]

Please help me to run AVD in my desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select software GLES from the Emulated performance in AVD settings and you're done, that's what I did and it worked for me.

[image]

Although I would use a 3rd party emulator like "Bluestacks" as it uses less memory and runs better especially on older PC's with a smaller amount of RAM.

Comment: Should I select Hardware or software GLES?

Comment: @AvisSiva Software GLES

Comment: will tell after try bro.

Comment: Wow bro its working. You save my laptop's life bro. very thank you. :)

Comment: Bro but please change the image which shows "Hardware GLES" selected. Then only it will be correct.